# The return type 'bool' isn't a 'KeyEventResult'as required by the closure's context

Tags: flutter, dart

```
if (event is RawKeyDownEvent &&
     (event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.space ||
      event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.enter ||
      event.logicalKey == LogicalKeyboardKey.numpadEnter)) 
        {
          widget.onPressed();
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
}`
```

When i ran this code error on return type 'bool' ins't a 'KeyEventResult' as required by the closure's context

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, it's required to return `KeyEventResult` (docs [link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/KeyEventResult-class.html)) where you've returned `true` or `false`.

Try checking it. Else if not working, then please share a more reproducible amount of code (like the whole function where this if belongs).

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir Sahil Sonawane